# Is the following property true?

Tags: fourier-transform

I was looking at a solution of a Fourier Transform question and following property was used, if:
$$ x(t)\rightarrow X(jw)                        $$
then:

$$    e^{jw_ot}x(t)\rightarrow X(j(w-w_0))             $$
$$    x(t)\sin(w_0t)\rightarrow \frac{1}{2j}X(j(w-w_0))   - \frac{1}{2j}X(j(w+w_0))                                        $$
If the above statements are true, can we say that for cos:

$$    x(t)\cos(w_0t)\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}X(j(w-w_0))   - \frac{1}{2}X(j(w-w_0))                                        $$

Comment: You ask whether $$ x(t)cos(w_0t)\rightarrow \frac{1}{2j}X(j(w-w_0))   - \frac{1}{2j}X(j(w-w_0)) $$ is a true statement.  Have you noticed that the right hand side is of the form $\alpha-\alpha$ and so must equal $0$?  That is, you are asking whether $$  x(t)cos(w_0t)\rightarrow 0$$ is true.  Can you answer your question for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\cos$, assuming $\omega_0$ is real, [the identity is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional):
$$
x(t) \cos(\omega_0)t = \frac{1}{2} X(j(\omega - \omega_0)) + \frac{1}{2} X(j(\omega + \omega_0))
$$

This is because
$$
\cos(\omega_0 t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{j \omega_0 t} + \frac{1}{2}e^{-j \omega_0 t}
$$

Use this expression with your first identity and the superposition property of the Fourier transform to arrive at this result.

As an aside, also note that
$$
\sin(\omega_0 t) = \frac{1}{2j}e^{j \omega_0 t} - \frac{1}{2j}e^{-j \omega_0 t}
$$
By the same reasoning, this is how you arrive at your second identity.